# Is it possible to create a code block of pseudocode in R Markdown/knitr?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I've tried using backticks and tildes, but they require languages. I just want a formatted code block of plain text with highlighted background.

Using `eval=FALSE` and `tidy=FALSE` works until reaching a keyword such as `if`, the subsequent code will be color highlighted in both the `.Rmd` file and the output PDF. Not specifying a language through the options removes the capability of background highlighting the code in the output.

````
```{r, eval=FALSE,tidy=FALSE}
loop through each species
    loop through each measurement of the current species
         if measurement ...
etc.
```
````

Comment: Does adding the chunk option eval=FALSE do what you want?

Comment: This doesn't work because code in a chunk is checked for validity, even if eval = FALSE

Edit: It seems things have changed in recent years - eval = FALSE should be enough. Sorry atiretoo!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's some sample code that renders to HTML just fine. It also renders correctly to Word and PDF.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

Here is some plain text.

Next, let's write some pseudo code.  Note that you don't _have_ to specify a language if using plain backticks.

```
object <- [some kind of calculation]
```

If you set `eval = FALSE` you can get the highlighted background

```{r, eval = FALSE}
object <- [some kind of calculation]
Note that this; is not valid R code
```

You may find it interesting that your example works just fine for me.

```{r, eval=FALSE}
loop through each species
    loop through each measurement of the current species
    ...
etc.
```
````

Comment: Not using brackets to set a language works, but it removes the option to background highlight the code.

Comment: I'm also not getting the highlighted background when I run that to any output format. I'm using R 3.2.3, RStudio  0.99.491, and knitr 1.11

Comment: This is the approach (without language section) I used, then knit to HTML and printed from there.

Answer (score 1):

Use tidy = FALSE

````
```{r, tidy=FALSE, eval=FALSE, highlight=FALSE }

pseudocode

```
````

edit: Added highlight, just in case you uniform color

Comment: This removes the grey background that signifies it as code in the output file.